# Share auth sessions across sub domains with multiple Laravel 5 installations

Tags: php, session, laravel, authentication, subdomain

I have two sub domains, each with their own installation of Laravel 5.1 and sharing the same database.

`app.project.dev` where the user can edit their project

`*.project.dev` where `*` is the username

I'm creating a website builder so when when the user views their site at `*.project.dev` I want to check if they are still logged into `app.project.dev` and show some extra functionality.

I've tried changing `'domain' => .project.dev` in `config/session.php` on both instances and get different session cookies. I presume this only works if different sub domains are using the same installation.

Comment: I would recommend using a database approach solution since both project share the same database. 
Simply flag the user as logged in the corresponding table, when you want to display more info, check the user's status and then show the extra functionality.

Comment: That sounds viable. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to tell the database to flag them as logged out, if they don't sign out themselves but then session times out?

Comment: You can fire an event to change the user's status as logged out when the session expires.

Comment: Actually, I think I do need the cookie session as *.project.dev is public and I need to match */username with matching session so only they can see the extra functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I just read up on that.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried it but here's an idea: configure both of your lavarel installations to use the same `storage` directory. This is where sessions are kept by default.

Otherwise, a [custom session driver](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#adding-custom-session-drivers) could be used, perhaps backed by your database.

Comment: Not yet, it's last on my list to do. Plus I'm using JTW auth for the admin area now and looking to see if that can help with cross domain sessions.